# WPF: How to attach events to enum-generated Context Menu?

Tags: wpf, enums, contextmenu

In my simple WPF App, I use contextmenu on the grid in a dynamic fashion: I get the items from an enum in case I expand it in the future. I want to do different actions based on which menu item the user clicks, but I can only fire the same event regardless of which item was clicked.

Here is the XAML code:

```
<Window
x:Class="ProcessViewer.MainWindow"
Title="Process Viewer"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProcessViewer"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
Height="350"
Width="525"
WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider
        x:Key="contextToEnum"
        MethodName="GetValues"
        ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:ProcessType" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>       
</Window.Resources>

<Grid
    x:Name="grid"
    Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu
            Name="menu"                
            MenuItem.Click="MenuButton_Click"
            ItemsSource="{Binding
                Source={StaticResource contextToEnum}}">
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>
</Grid>
```

I tried to attach a click event on the Context Menu and then cast its object argument into a Context Menu, but I can only access the name of the Context Menu (not those of its items) and other properties like Width and Height etc.

Here is the relelvant part of the Code-Behind:

```
private void MenuButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ContextMenu choice = sender as ContextMenu;
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked: " + choice.Name.ToString());

    }
```

Is there a way to attach separate *events* or *controls* to each of the items? The problem would, of course, be that I don't know in advance how many items will the enum hold, so the ideal solution would be something like this:

```
if(clikedOnItem == enum.OneOfTheItems)
   {
       DoSomething()
   }
else if (clikedOnItem == enum.Anotheritem)
   {
       DoSomethingElse()
   }
```

etc.

Since I will work with a maximum of 5-15 enum elements, I could do all the menu items manually, but I would like to find a more "intelligent" workaround, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to handle the Click event of each MenuItem using an ItemContainerStyle with an EventTrigger:

```
<ContextMenu Name="menu" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource contextToEnum}}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="MenuButton_Click" />
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

...and then cast the sender argument to a `MenuItem` and access the enum value through the DataContext property of the `MenuItem`:

```
private void MenuButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem choice = sender as MenuItem;
    ProcessType val = (ProcessType)choice.DataContext;
}
```